# What is the best way to clean shoelaces?

Tags: cleaning, shoes

I had snow white shoelaces on a pair of brand new sneakers, but Nature wasn't having it and they're splattered green and brown by now. I tried washing laces before in soap and water, but they tend to become "fuzzy", stretch, and gradually fall apart. What would be the best way to clean them out without stretching, damaging, or ruining them?

Comment: My **hack** is to buy a different colour shoelace, or multi-colour laces, that match your trousers/pants instead of the shoe.

Comment: But the white laces looks so nice, and that doesn't tell me how to clean shoelaces...

Comment: Is it worth the trouble? You can buy a pack of 40 laces for just a few GBP.

Comment: Well, I _am_ talking about Merrell sneakers, and I think it'll be cheaper to clean them than replace, unless cleaning shoelaces is that big of a hassle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier something is to do, the more likely you'll do it. If it's quick, so much the better.

Treat the laces as you would other easily damaged (delicate) garments. Put them in a mesh bag to reduce the wear-and-tear of the wash cycle.

Keep them clean as you would your white trousers. Don't wait until they become stained and grimy. Periodically, remove 'em, bag 'em, wash 'em, and dry 'em.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind and not let stains ferment :P

Comment: **That's** the word I was trying to think of… @snekprogrammer

Answer (score 1):

I clean my shoes often right now. Soak them in Oxygen bleach for 5-10 minutes. Then run them in the washing machine on a GENTLE setting. It should come out as white as it can get.